# How to convert object to query string in Java?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to convert the following object to query string, so that can be used with GET request.

```
Class A {
  String prop1;
  String prop2;
  Date date1;
  Date date2;
  ClassB objB;
}

Class B {
 String prop3;
 String prop4;
}
```

We can do that first object to Map then convert map to MultiValueMap and use URIComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("httpL//example.com").queryParams(multiValueMap).build();

Is there shorter and better way of converting object to query string so that be used with GET request in Spring Project for Junit Test?

Comment: Are you trying to do this "automatically", or can you build the key/value pairs manually? That is, are you trying to take the fields/values from an arbitrary object and convert them into a query string? Or do you simply want to create queries from one well-known, hard-codeable, class?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do automatically. I do not want to write quey param for each parameter.

Comment: You could create your own utility method that uses reflection to build the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why convert to `Map` then `MultiValueMap`, instead of just building it directly?

```
DateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("whatever date format you want");
URIComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("httpL//example.com")
                    .queryParam("prop1", a.prop1)
                    .queryParam("prop2", a.prop2)
                    .queryParam("date1", dateFmt.format(a.date1))
                    .queryParam("date2", dateFmt.format(a.date2))
                    .queryParam("prop3", a.objB.prop3)
                    .queryParam("prop4", a.objB.prop4)
                    .build();
```

Comment: We can use this. But what if there are many parameters in the object? Then for every single object we need to write query param. Is this the better approach?

Comment: Web servers often limit the length of a URL, so there is a limit to how many query parameters you can add to a URL. If you really need to send objects with lots of values, you should use a POST, not a GET, and then the payload can even be complex nested values, e.g. XML or JSON.

Comment: And how to deal with 20+ params object with lists and maps? Is there a better way?

Comment: @BubenIvanov If you have a question, you should create a question, and supply more information than you did in your comment, because I have no idea how you intend "lists and maps" to apply to this.

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own method that uses `java.lang.reflect`. Here's an example

```
public static String getRequestString(String urlString, Class clazz, Object o){
    String queryString = "?";

    try {
        for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            queryString += queryString.concat(f.getName() + "=" + String.valueOf(f.get(o)) + "&");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return urlString + queryString.substring(0,queryString.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: I took reference from you answer and posting my answer for better clarrity

Comment: It works but you should write 
queryString = queryString.concat(f.getName() + "=" + String.valueOf(f.get(o)) + "&"); instead of queryString += queryString.concat(f.getName() + "=" + String.valueOf(f.get(o)) + "&"); (remove the "+") else you will concat itself each time you want add a field

Answer (score 1):

OpenFeign has the annotation `@QueryMap` to generate query params dinamicaly based on a object attributes:

```
public interface Api {
  @RequestLine("GET /find")
  V find(@QueryMap CustomPojo customPojo);
}
```

See more at:
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#dynamic-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it,

Create Map, populate and then iterate over map items and append to builder this seems to be working for me. It does not cover support for nested objects. Should be simple with recursion.

```
public String getRequestString(Class clazz, Object o) {
        StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        final Map<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try {
            for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                queryParams.put(f.getName(), String.valueOf(f.get(o)));
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
                queryStringBuilder.append(testStringUtils.toSnakeCase(entry.getKey()));
                queryStringBuilder.append("=");
                queryStringBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
                queryStringBuilder.append("&");
            }
            logger.info("Map: " + queryParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String queryString = queryStringBuilder.toString();
        logger.info("Query string : " + queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() - 1));
        return "?" + queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() - 1);
```